# Mapping position of QLabel on an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, crop

I'm trying to segment an image using Qlabels, these Qlabels are placed on an image then the segmentation will be done by pressing the segment button,  I have done working on cropping function, its work but the result of the cropped images are not matched with the exact location of labels on the image.

Here is my code:

```
def crop(self):
    i=1
    image = self.UserImageLbl.pixmap()

    for label in self.labels:
        currentQRect = label.geometry()
        #pixmap_rect = self.UserImageLbl.geometry()
        tr = QtGui.QTransform()
        r = tr.mapRect(currentQRect)

        cropQPixmap = image.copy(r)
        cropQPixmap.save('OUT '+str(i)+'.png')
        i=i+1
```

Complete Code example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap, QPainter, QCursor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QMimeData, Qt

class DraggableLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setStyleSheet("border-color: rgb(238, 0, 0); border-width : 2.0px; border-style:inset; background: transparent;")
        self.origin = None

    def setLimits(self, rect):
        self.limits = rect

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.origin:
            # update the origin point, we'll need that later
            self.origin = self.pos()
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.mousePos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # move the box
            self.move(self.pos() + event.pos() - self.mousePos)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # if the box is not within the image boundaries, move it
            # back to the original position
            if not self.limits.contains(self.geometry()):
                self.move(self.origin)


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.setEnabled(True)
        Dialog.resize(1050, 800)
        Dialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1050, 800))
        Dialog.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1050, 800))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../.designer/backup/project pic/images icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(217, 217, 217);\n"
"background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);")
        self.BrowesImageButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.BrowesImageButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 60, 200, 60))
        self.BrowesImageButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 60))
        self.BrowesImageButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)

        self.BrowesImageButton.setFont(font)
        self.BrowesImageButton.setStyleSheet("")
        self.BrowesImageButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.BrowesImageButton.setObjectName("BrowesImageButton")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Dialog)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 170, 211, 131))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.groupBox.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.checkBox_Short = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.groupBox)
        self.checkBox_Short.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 141, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Adobe Heiti Std R")
        font.setPointSize(10)

        self.checkBox_Short.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox_Short.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.checkBox_Short.setObjectName("checkBox_Short")
        self.checkBox_Short.setEnabled(False)

        self.checkBox_Long = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.groupBox)
        self.checkBox_Long.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 141, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Adobe Heiti Std R")
        font.setPointSize(10)

        self.checkBox_Long.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox_Long.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.checkBox_Long.setObjectName("checkBox_Long")
        self.checkBox_Long.setEnabled(False)

        self.SegmentImageButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.SegmentImageButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(830, 330, 200, 60))
        self.SegmentImageButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 60))
        self.SegmentImageButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 60))

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.SegmentImageButton.setFont(font)
        self.SegmentImageButton.setStyleSheet("")
        self.SegmentImageButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.SegmentImageButton.setObjectName("SegmentImageButton")
        self.SegmentImageButton.setEnabled(False)

        self.UserImageLbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.UserImageLbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 750, 500))
        self.UserImageLbl.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(750, 500))
        self.UserImageLbl.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(750, 500))
        self.UserImageLbl.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.UserImageLbl.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.UserImageLbl.setLineWidth(1)
        self.UserImageLbl.setMidLineWidth(0)
        self.UserImageLbl.setText("")
        self.UserImageLbl.setScaledContents(False)
        self.UserImageLbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.UserImageLbl.setObjectName("UserImageLbl")

        self.buttonGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.checkBox_Short)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.checkBox_Long)

        self.label_1 = DraggableLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2 = DraggableLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3 = DraggableLabel(Dialog)

        self.label_1.move(820, 470)
        self.label_2.move(900, 470)
        self.label_3.move(980, 470)

        self.labels = [self.label_1, self.label_2, self.label_3]
        for label in self.labels:
            label.hide()
            label.raise_()

        self.BrowesImageButton.clicked.connect(self.setImage)
        self.checkBox_Long.toggled.connect(self.setBoxSizes)
        self.checkBox_Short.toggled.connect(self.setBoxSizes)
        self.SegmentImageButton.clicked.connect(self.crop)


    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Cropping"))
        self.BrowesImageButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Select Image"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Choose Type"))
        self.checkBox_Short.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Short "))
        self.checkBox_Long.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Long "))
        self.SegmentImageButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Segment Image"))

    def setImage(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select Image", "", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *jpeg *.bmp)") # Ask for file

        if fileName: # If the user gives a file
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(fileName) # Setup pixmap with the provided image
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.UserImageLbl.width(), self.UserImageLbl.height(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio) # Scale pixmap
            self.UserImageLbl.setPixmap(pixmap) # Set the pixmap onto the label
            self.UserImageLbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) # Align the label to center
            #UserImageLbl = DropLabel()
            self.checkBox_Short.setEnabled(True)
            self.checkBox_Long.setEnabled(True)

    def setBoxSizes(self):
        if self.checkBox_Short.isChecked():
            self.SegmentImageButton.setEnabled(True)
            boxSize = 80
        else:
            boxSize = 60
            self.SegmentImageButton.setEnabled(True)


        for label in self.labels:
            label.setFixedSize(boxSize, boxSize)
            label.setLimits(self.UserImageLbl.geometry())
            label.show()

    def crop(self):
        i=1
        image = self.UserImageLbl.pixmap()

        for label in self.labels:
            currentQRect = label.geometry()
            #pixmap_rect = self.UserImageLbl.geometry()
            tr = QtGui.QTransform()
            r = tr.mapRect(currentQRect)

            cropQPixmap = image.copy(r)
            cropQPixmap.save('OUT '+str(i)+'.png')
            i=i+1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

can someone tell me what's wrong with my code!
Thanks

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: The question was updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all do not modify the code generated by Qt Designer but you must create a class that inherits from a widget and use the generated class to fill it.

On the other hand considering the above a simpler solution than to make a crop in the QPixmap is to record a section of the window.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class DraggableLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet(
            "border-color: rgb(238, 0, 0); border-width : 2.0px; border-style:inset; background: transparent;"
        )
        self.origin = QtCore.QPoint()

    def setLimits(self, rect):
        self.limits = rect

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.origin.isNull():
            self.origin = self.pos()
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.mousePos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.move(self.pos() + event.pos() - self.mousePos)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            if not self.limits.contains(self.geometry()):
                self.move(self.origin)


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.setEnabled(True)
        Dialog.resize(1050, 800)
        Dialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1050, 800))
        Dialog.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1050, 800))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(
            QtGui.QPixmap("../.designer/backup/project pic/images icon.png"),
            QtGui.QIcon.Normal,
            QtGui.QIcon.Off,
        )
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: rgb(217, 217, 217);\n"
            "background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);"
        )
        self.BrowesImageButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.BrowesImageButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 60, 200, 60))
        self.BrowesImageButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 60))
        self.BrowesImageButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)

        self.BrowesImageButton.setFont(font)
        self.BrowesImageButton.setStyleSheet("")
        self.BrowesImageButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.BrowesImageButton.setObjectName("BrowesImageButton")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Dialog)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(820, 170, 211, 131))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.groupBox.setFont(font)
        self.groupBox.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.checkBox_Short = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.groupBox)
        self.checkBox_Short.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 141, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Adobe Heiti Std R")
        font.setPointSize(10)

        self.checkBox_Short.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox_Short.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.checkBox_Short.setObjectName("checkBox_Short")
        self.checkBox_Short.setEnabled(False)

        self.checkBox_Long = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.groupBox)
        self.checkBox_Long.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 141, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Adobe Heiti Std R")
        font.setPointSize(10)

        self.checkBox_Long.setFont(font)
        self.checkBox_Long.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.checkBox_Long.setObjectName("checkBox_Long")
        self.checkBox_Long.setEnabled(False)

        self.SegmentImageButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.SegmentImageButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(830, 330, 200, 60))
        self.SegmentImageButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 60))
        self.SegmentImageButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 60))

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.SegmentImageButton.setFont(font)
        self.SegmentImageButton.setStyleSheet("")
        self.SegmentImageButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.SegmentImageButton.setObjectName("SegmentImageButton")
        self.SegmentImageButton.setEnabled(False)

        self.UserImageLbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.UserImageLbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 750, 500))
        self.UserImageLbl.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(750, 500))
        self.UserImageLbl.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(750, 500))
        self.UserImageLbl.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.UserImageLbl.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.UserImageLbl.setLineWidth(1)
        self.UserImageLbl.setMidLineWidth(0)
        self.UserImageLbl.setText("")
        self.UserImageLbl.setScaledContents(False)
        self.UserImageLbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.UserImageLbl.setObjectName("UserImageLbl")

        self.buttonGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.checkBox_Short)
        self.buttonGroup.addButton(self.checkBox_Long)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Cropping"))
        self.BrowesImageButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Select Image"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Choose Type"))
        self.checkBox_Short.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Short "))
        self.checkBox_Long.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Long "))
        self.SegmentImageButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Segment Image"))


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.label_1 = DraggableLabel(self)
        self.label_2 = DraggableLabel(self)
        self.label_3 = DraggableLabel(self)

        self.label_1.move(820, 470)
        self.label_2.move(900, 470)
        self.label_3.move(980, 470)

        self.labels = [self.label_1, self.label_2, self.label_3]
        for label in self.labels:
            label.hide()
            label.raise_()

        self.BrowesImageButton.clicked.connect(self.setImage)
        self.checkBox_Long.toggled.connect(self.setBoxSizes)
        self.checkBox_Short.toggled.connect(self.setBoxSizes)
        self.SegmentImageButton.clicked.connect(self.crop)

    def setImage(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None, "Select Image", "", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *jpeg *.bmp)"
        )  # Ask for file

        if fileName:  # If the user gives a file
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(fileName)  # Setup pixmap with the provided image
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(
                self.UserImageLbl.width(),
                self.UserImageLbl.height(),
                QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
            )  # Scale pixmap
            self.UserImageLbl.setPixmap(pixmap)  # Set the pixmap onto the label
            self.UserImageLbl.setAlignment(
                QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
            )  # Align the label to center
            # UserImageLbl = DropLabel()
            self.checkBox_Short.setEnabled(True)
            self.checkBox_Long.setEnabled(True)

    def setBoxSizes(self):
        if self.checkBox_Short.isChecked():
            self.SegmentImageButton.setEnabled(True)
            boxSize = 80
        else:
            boxSize = 60
            self.SegmentImageButton.setEnabled(True)

        for label in self.labels:
            label.setFixedSize(boxSize, boxSize)
            label.setLimits(self.UserImageLbl.geometry())
            label.show()

    def crop(self):
        base_rect = self.UserImageLbl.geometry()

        for i, label in enumerate(self.labels, 1):

            label_r = label.geometry()
            res_rect = base_rect.intersected(label_r)
            if not res_rect.isNull():
                label.hide()
                pixmap = self.grab(res_rect)
                label.show()
                pixmap.save("OUT{}.png".format(i))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```